# pandas.pivot_table : How to name functions for aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pivot-table

I am trying to pivot pandas DataFrame using several aggregate functions, some of which are lambda. There has to be a distinct name for each column in order to have aggregations by several lambda functions. I tried a few ideas I found online but none worked. This is the minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 4, 5, 6], 'col3': [7, 10, 8, 9]})

pivoted_df = df.pivot_table(index = ['col1', 'col2'], values  = 'col3', aggfunc=[('lam1', lambda x: np.percentile(x, 50)), ('lam2', np.percentile(x, 75)]).reset_index()
```

The error is

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'lam1'
```

I tried with `dictionary`, it also results in error. Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name the functions explicitly:

```
def lam1(x):
    return np.percentile(x, 50)

def lam2(x):
    return np.percentile(x, 75)

pivoted_df = df.pivot_table(index = ['col1', 'col2'], values  = 'col3',
                            aggfunc=[lam1, lam2]).reset_index()
```

Your aggregation series will then be appropriately named:

```
print(pivoted_df)

   col1  col2  lam1  lam2
0     1     4   8.5  9.25
1     2     5   8.0  8.00
2     3     6   9.0  9.00
```

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) for `pd.pivot_table` explain why:

> **aggfunc** : function, list of functions, dict, default numpy.mean
>
> If list of functions passed, **the resulting pivot table will have
>   hierarchical columns whose top level are the function names** (*inferred
>   from the function objects themselves*) If dict is passed, the key is
>   column to aggregate and value is function or list of functions

Comment: @Marina, Sure, I mean jezrael's solution *works* no problem. You may wish to take note of this statement in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): `Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier.` The `lambda` naming solution is an example of the latter.

Comment: many thanks. Both solutions worked, I accepted yours as they were equally informative, however yours came somewhat faster. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I suggest use here [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
f1 = lambda x: np.percentile(x, 50)
f2 = lambda x: np.percentile(x, 75)

pivoted_df = (df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3']
                .agg([('lam1', f1), ('lam2', f2)])
                .reset_index())
print (pivoted_df)
   col1  col2  lam1  lam2
0     1     4   8.5  9.25
1     2     5   8.0  8.00
2     3     6   9.0  9.00
```